# Property update does not change value in component

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to display some text based on what time it is, and I have a time property that stores the current time. I want the time on the text to be updated as time passes, but it never updates, and is stuck on the time when it first ran. And since the time never updates, I can't use the `visible` condition to display my text. What can I do to fix this code to make sure the values update here?

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    height: 400
    width: 400
    property real time: new Date().getTime()
    property real hour: new Date().getHours()
    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        width: 400; height: 400
        color: "white"
        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: "Good morning, the time is: " + time
            // visible: hour > 4 && hour < 12
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your binding won't work because you're binding to a javascript function that doesn't send a changed signal. You need to use a Timer for this:

```
Window {
    visible: true
    height: 400
    width: 400
    property real time: new Date().getTime()
    property real hour: new Date().getHours()

    Timer {
        running: true
        repeat: true
        interval: 60000 // Update every 60 seconds maybe?
        onTriggered: {
            time = new Date().getTime()
            hour = new Date().getHours()
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        width: 400; height: 400
        color: "white"
        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: "Good morning, the time is: " + time
            visible: hour > 4 && hour < 12
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any other way we could do this without using a Timer?

Comment: Why? What's wrong with a Timer?